# Multiple SELECT statements on the same table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following example table:

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+
| device_id | execution_id | severity |
+-----------+--------------+----------+
|       id1 | 86g8g5t3tz4e |     INFO |
|           | 86g8g5t3tz4e |     INFO |
|           | 86g8g5t3tz4e |    ERROR |
|       id2 | 86g8t0gk9t8k |     INFO |
|           | 86g8t0gk9t8k |     INFO |
|           | 86g8t0gk9t8k |     INFO |
|       id3 | ox1fl5e4gpxa |     INFO |
|           | ox1fl5e4gpxa |     INFO |
|           | ox1fl5e4gpxa |    ERROR |
+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

Where I have logs from an internal system. `deviceId` is guaranteed to be found at the beginning on each execution.

I'd like to get all `device_id`s which their `execution_id` ends with an `ERROR`. I can get all the `execution_id`s like that:

```sql
SELECT execution_id as id FROM `my_table` WHERE severity = "ERROR" LIMIT 1000
```

How do I correlate it with the `deviceId`s? Am I looking for multiple `SELECT`s? A `GROUP BY`? A `JOIN`?

Thanks

Comment: you can't.  Order of records  isn't guaranteed in a database table.  The device_ID would have to be on every record. or we have to have a guarantee that the device_ID _REPEATS for every row until a new ID is encountered but since order isn't guaranteed, even this woudln't work... This table is not built in 3rd normal from so standard joins wouldn't work.  Or we'd have to have a row number  Maybe if we can guarantee execution_ID is unique per device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the error rows lack the device IDs, so you must find them in the table using the execution ID.

Probably the easiest way to do that is aggregation:

```
select execution_id, max(device_id)
from mytable
group by execution_id
having max(case when severity = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Can you explain how's that query works? Also, what do I need to add if as next level it'd like to get a list of distinct `device_id`s?

Comment: Per execution ID the query looks at all rows, takes the maximum device ID (there is just one per execution ID) and checks whether there is an error row. If there isn't, then the execution ID gets dismissed. If you want a list of distinct device IDs from here, then `select distinct max(device_id)` instead.